# Stuck with Python if-else one line statement

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm facing issue with nested one line conditional statement while there is a assignment operation.

````
bob   = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(alice, bob)
a, b = 0
for i in range(3):
    a+=1 if alice[i]>bob[i] else (b+=1 if alice[i]<bob[i] else 1)
print(a,b)```

Output: <br/>
File "/home/Algorithms/compare_triplets.py", line 6    
a+=1 if alice[i]>bob[i] else b=b+1 if alice[i]<bob[i] else 1
````

Comment: Python does not support one-line if/else statements. Use more lines.

Comment: What you think is a "one line conditional statement" is conditional *expression* syntax, which selects one of two *values*. It does not select one of two statements to execute.

Comment: It can be done, but consider the mountain of evidence which indicates that this is poor design: https://www.google.com/search?q=thedailywtf.com+tern&oq=thedailywtf.com+tern&aqs=chrome..69i57.3855j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use statements like `a += 1` in an in-line if else statement. Only values are allowed, and `a += 1` is not a value. You'll have to use a multi-line if-elif-else instead (which, by the way, is generally considered to be more readable anyway).

Comment: A nitpick: `a += 1` is not an expression at all, but a statement. Indeed, if it _were_ an expression, this syntax would work! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on one line, this works (but is a bad idea):

```
a, b = a + 1 if alice[i] > bob[1] else a, b + 1 if alice[i] < bob[i] else b
```

However, it's unclear what you expected the `else 1` bit to achieve.

What's wrong with:

```
if alice[i] > bob[1]:
    a += 1
elif alice[i] < bob[1]:
    b += 1
else:
    # whatever you wanted with the `else 1`
    pass
```

Sure, it's a few more lines, but it's actually only 60 functional characters, instead of 75, so if you're going for brevity, it's better.

Answer (score 0):

Code provided by you is bit unclear and does not explain clear goal. Here is the a code which based on my assumptions achieve a close goal:

```
  bob   = list(map(int, input().split()))
 print(alice, bob)
 a, b = 0
for i in range(3):

if alice[i]>bob[i]:
    a+=1 
else:
    b+=1
 print(a,b)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score -1):

bob   = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(alice, bob)
a, b = 0
for i in range(3):
a = alice[i] > bob[1] ? a += 1 : a;
b = alice[i] < bob[1] ? b += 1 : b;
print(a,b)

## I think you want this!!! :)

Answer (score -1):

bob   = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(alice, bob)
a, b = 0
for i in range(3):
a = alice[i] > bob[1] ? a += 1 : a;
b = alice[i] < bob[1] ? b += 1 : b;
print(a,b)